# forward_list iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++

When I do a homework ,I got the error"forward_list iterator not incrementable"
The following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list>
#include<initializer_list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    forward_list<int> lis{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto pre = lis.before_begin();
    auto curr = lis.begin();
    for (auto i :lis)
    {
        if (i & 0x1)
            curr = lis.erase_after(pre);
        else
        {
            pre=curr;
            curr++;
        }
    }
    for (auto i : lis)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I try to use the "for each" loop to solve this problem istead of the range of iterator(this is just a temporary thought),and I find that in the second loop the "pre" iterator seems to become invalid.but when I use the range of iterator to solve this problem.it's will be ok:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list>
#include<initializer_list>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    forward_list<int> lis{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto pre = lis.before_begin();
    auto curr = lis.begin();
    while (curr != lis.end())
    {
        if (*curr & 0x1)
            curr = lis.erase_after(pre);
        else
        {
            pre=curr;
            curr++;
        }
    }
    for (auto i : lis)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I saw many similar questions but could not find the answer. Hope everyone can help me.Thanks!

Comment: Do you `include<forward_list>` and also do you compile with `std=c++11` ?

Comment: That's not your code. There's no way this could come close to compiling. As to what seems to be the question, the `pre` iterator isn't mentioned in the second loop, so it doesn't matter whether it's valid. What is the actual problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong expression，"the second loop" mean that “the second execution in the first loop body" @Pete Becker

Comment: The head file is included and the code is run with c++11@ KostasRim

Comment: Okay, that's clearer. Still, you should post code that actually compiles.

Comment: The whole code is add to the original content @Pete Becker

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing most of the `#include` directives, since they aren't needed in this code. When I compile and run it I get three lines of output, showing 2 4 and 6, which seems sensible. Are you getting something different?

Comment: Are you running the first block code?When I run the code the compiler reported an error“forward_list iterator not incrementable” the code is run with vs2013@Pete Becker

Comment: "pre" represent off_the beginning iterator and "curr" represent the current iterator @molbdnilo

Comment: @庞小震 -- What is the goal of your program?   Is it to remove all odd elements from the list?   If so, there are much easier ways to do this, such as simply using `forward_list::remove_if`.

Comment: Thanks for you advise, the goal is  to remove all odd elements from the list .there many easier way to solve this problem, but I want to konw what's wrong with my code. @ PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @庞小震 -- The problem with your code is that you are altering the container inside of the range-based `for` loop that uses the container as the index.  That is not going to work.  Either use use a "regular" loop, or as suggested already, use `lis.remove_if([](int n) {return n %1;});`.  No mistakes, no loop, and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot .@ PaulMcKenzie